# Using jQuery show/hide nested divs

Tags: jquery, html

I can't get the following jquery to work for example if I have clicked a box and leave it open and then click another box the second box clicked closes the first box but the second box is not displayed until I click the second box again how can I get my code so that the second box for example closes all other open boxes and the displays its contents with out clicking it a second time?

HTML code:

```
<div class="button">
    <a class="remove">Remove</a> 
    <a class="time">Time</a>
    <a class="space">Space</a> 
    more links......

    <div class="container">
        <div class="firs-container">
            .......
        </div>

        <div class="sec-container">
            .......
        </div>

        <div class="third-container">
            .......
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.remove, a.cancel').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.button').find('.container:first').children().hide();
        $(this).closest('.button').find('.container:first').fadeToggle('slow', 'linear');
        $(this).closest('.button').find('.sec-container:first').fadeToggle('slow', 'linear');
        // prevent default action
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be moved, but I still want to give you a hint (if you're using jQuery 1.7.x)

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function($)
{
    $( '.selector' ).on( 'click', function()
    {
        // do stuff
    } );
} );
```

<sup>Mind the WP/jQuery no conflict mode and make shure you're inside a properly wrapped function » check your console for errors</sup>